# glob in giving only first file that matched pattern

Tags: c++, glob

I want to get a file list in a folder, using `glob.h` in C++.

Consider the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "glob.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    glob_t globResult;
    string filePath = argv[1];
    glob(filePath.c_str(),0,NULL,&globResult);
    cout<<"No. of files found:"<<globResult.gl_pathc<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < globResult.gl_pathc; i++)
    {
            cout << string(globResult.gl_pathv[i]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In a folder for following files:

```
Images\
    |- cat.jpeg
    |- dog.jpg
    |- rat.jpg
```

when I run `Image ./Images/*`, I only get cat.jpeg, instead of all three files.

What am I doing wrong?

Compiled using `g++ 6.3` and `clang++ 5.0`.

Comment: What's the output of `cout<<"No. of files found:"<<globResult.gl_pathc<<endl;`?

Comment: Also what is the return value of the `glob` call?

Comment: You need to put the arg in quotes -- `'./Images/*'` -- otherwise the shell will interpret the glob before you get a chance to.

Comment: @giovanni it's 1

Comment: @g. M. Yes!!! That was it. With quotes it's coming fine. Thanks! You can put your comment as answer and I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment... all command line args to an executable will, generally speaking, be interpreted by the shell *before* being passed to your app.  So, given the file hierarchy...

```
Images\
  |- cat.jpeg
  |- dog.jpg
  |- rat.jpg
```

The command...

```
Image ./Images/*
```

will actually result in...

```
Image ./Images/cat.jpeg ./Images/dog.jpg ./Images/rat.jpg
```

So the first parameter passed to `glob` in your code will be `./Images/cat.jpeg` and, hence, that will be the only match.  To avoid shell expansion simply quote the arg...

```
Image './Images/*'
```